# Система для печати чеков на складе по печатным формам из 1С

Tags: java, linux, 1с, jasperreports

Не хватает опыта решить задачу:

1. Есть БД 1С стоит в ЦОД. К ней доступ закрыт извне, можно к ней подключиться только на месте каким-то сервером, или еще чем.
2. Есть удаленный склад. На нем работники у которых в руках мобилки с приложением на Андроиде.
3. На этом складе есть принтер для чеков, на который с мобилки нужно слать на печать всякие чеки и прочее по определенной печатной форме, которая берется из 1С из п1.

Нужно:

- Передавать печатные формы из 1С, что в ЦОД-е на складской сервер/ПК/или еще что-то.
- По этим печатным формам из мобилки печатать чеки на принтер чеков.

1С на складе ставить нельзя, нужно что-то бесплатное :(:(:(:(

Может есть какие-то уже готовые решения для этого? Или может кто подскажет хоть примерно куда копать. У меня идея только писать сервер для ЦОД-а и писать сервер для склада, чтобы крутились на Линуксе.
Чтобы ЦОД-овский сервер рассылал формы на складские (их несколько будет). Например в формате pdf (что предпочтительней всего) Тот у себя их хранил и запрашивал время от времени новые печатные формы. А приложение "общалось" с локальным сервером и запрашивало печать по форме. Но тут такая фигня. Складской сервер должен будет как-то принимать данные из приложения на Андроиде, например через HTTP GET/POST (или как еще...) и формировать по имеющейся форме файл для печати и потом его слать на принтер чеков.

Пока что думаю о Jasper Reports. Но я не уверен, что он сможет выполнить все необходимые действия. А так же это решение может быть не бесплатным. И еще я нашел в открытом доступе только библиотеку и так же не уверен, что это сможет помочь в решении моего вопроса.

https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports

Comment: Если чеки фискальные, то никакой jasperreports вам не поможет. В кассе свой механизм создания чеков. Если же не фискальный, то можно хоть на html формы делать

Comment: Я смотрел на эту jasperreports... как раз для печати чеков. Но эта штука слишком сложная и не достаточно функциональная при этом. Я рендерил это дело через cairo. Но в вашем случае есть одинеска - если кто умеет с ней работать - делайте через неё.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет. Все было бы очень просто, если бы можно было установить на складе 1С, или «подружить» приложение с главной БД 1С, что в ЦОД. Но ставят задачу, как всегда, исходя из максимальной дешевизны :) В общем прямого сообщения с 1С, к сожалению, нет :( Так что, думаю придется писать сервер на линуксе крутящийся. И пихать в него функционал приема файлов с удаленного и в нем же «соединять» инфу с мобилки и печатную форму. Наверное )

Answer (score 0):

1с у вас на сервере уже есть. сервер 1с формирует форму чека и складывает в папочку. Сервер на складе смотрит папку, скачивает оттуда форму и стандартной командой печати отправляет в cups.

Если принтер не совместим с купс, то по перегонять в картинку и печатать в ком порт

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ! Буду думать ) Понимаю, что вопрос не совсем по теме форума, но я даже не знал куда шевелиться )